# Interpreting callgrind data

Tags: valgrind, graphviz, callgrind

I need a dynamic call graph for my app. I run it with `callgrind` tool (`valgrind` suite) and got `callgrind.out.xxxxx` file. Now, I want to make a graphical representation of this data. `KCacheGrind` doesn't help me much because it draws a limited part of the graph (draws ~50 functions instead of ~1500 profiled and I don't know how to fix that). How can I get a graph image where all of the functions will be drawn?

Comment: Does the callgrind.out contain data that's missing in the graph? Also, if you sort by "self", is there relevant time/instructions left that's spent in functions not listed? I can't remember a case where relevant parts were left out.

Comment: Yes, callgrind.out contains all the data I need (including functions missing in the graph) and most of the functions that aren't listed in the graph have relevant time/instructions spent. Don't know why `KCacheGrind` draws only part of it. UPD: if I choose the function I want in the list of functions (placed in the left in default `KCacheGrind` layout) then graph is redrawn to display this functions, but still missing others. I need the whole graph at once. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok, I've found the way. The generated `callgrind.out` file you can convert to `dot` file using [gprof2dot](https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot) (yes, this tool can parse `callgrind` files as well). And then you can get the graph image using `dot -T<type> dotfile.dot -o graphfile.<type>`

Comment: Interesting. Is the generated graph readable for 1500 functions?

Comment: The deal is that actually I need to compare two graphs from two different versions of software, so there is no aim to read/understand the whole graph, I need only some paths and I know where I should look for them. OTOH, generation `png` image takes about 5 minutes on my `Core i7-2600 3.4GHz / 8 Gb DDR3` an resulting file's size is 23 MBytes. Not all image viewers can handle it fast and correctly (perfect stress-test IMO :) )

Comment: are we supposed to actually type in the `-T<type>` ? or do we replace `<type>` with something?

Comment: @nmz787 yes you need to specify the type. e.g. `dot -Tsvg dotfile.dot -o graphfile.svg`. You can also use pdf or png amongst others.

Answer (score 38):

Using the following command to generate graph.png using gprof2dot

```
$ ./gprof2dot.py --format=callgrind --output=out.dot /path/to/callgrind.out
$ dot -Tpng out.dot -o graph.png
```